# Parameterized instrumentation tests on Android

Tags: android, junit, instrumentation, spoon

I'm trying to write a batched instrumentation test (using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`) for a particular `Activity` where I change the intent each time the test runs. I can do this with a single test, and just loop through stopping and restarting the Activity with the new intent, but this is not what I want. One reason is they really should be separate test runs. The other reason is, I'm using [Spoon](https://github.com/square/spoon) to generate a report when the tests finish, and the report will rightly think I only ran one test.

What I would like is it to treat a single test as a possibly infinite number of tests, and pass the data into the test each time the test runs.

Unfortunately you can't use [Theories](https://blogs.oracle.com/jacobc/entry/junit_theories) because it results in a RuntimeException where the InstrumentationTestRunner can't find my tests. Anyone have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just create a "testing" intent.   In order to simulate the relaunching of the application, make a method or several methods that reset all your static variables between tests.  Then you can test the classes from within a testing intent inside the application itself using

```
assert("value", MyClass.myMethod);
resetStatics();
assert(true, MyClass,myMethod);
resetStatics();
```

I don't know how much this will help you, if at all, but this is how I started writing my own tests.

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered that you can add a `public static Test suite()` method to a test class, and when you run just this single test class, `InstrumentationTestRunner` will run the `Test` returned by this method. This is helpful because `suite()` can explicitly call any constructor of your `TestCase`, including one with parameters.

Comment: I was looking for passing data to test methods, not the class

Comment: @ChristopherPerry Creating a new test object for each value you want to test is the standard JUnit paradigm.

Comment: that's not necessarily true. See here: https://blogs.oracle.com/jacobc/entry/junit_theories, it makes no sense to create a new test object when my test method is exactly the same, only with different data.